# How to prove this inequality containing cofactors of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, positive-definite

I want to prove that the matrix $A$ of order $n$ with $(a_{ij})=\frac{2^{i+j}-2^{|i-j|}}{3}$ admits a Cholesky factorization. $A$ is trivially symmetric, but when trying to show it is positive definite I have had some issues. First, we prove $det(A)>0$ by induction:

Case $n=1$:

$A = \left(\frac{2^{2}-2^{0}}{3}\right)$, so $det(A)=1>0$.

We assume $det(A)>0$ for all matrices of order $n$.

Then, for order $n+1$ we develop the determinant from the first column, assuming $n$ is even:
$$det(A) = (-1)^{1+1}a_{11}|A_{11}|+(-1)^{2+1}a_{21}|A_{21}|+\dots+(-1)^{n+1+1}a_{n+1,1}|A_{n+1,1}|$$
If we develop the $a_{ij}$ terms we have that:
$$det(A)=\sum_{i=0}^n (-2)^i|A_{i+1,1}|$$

Now, we have to prove that $2^0|A_{11}|-2|A_{21}|+2^2|A_{31}|-\dots+2^n|A_{n+1,1}|>0$. But at this point I guess it is not enough that the $|A_{ij}|>0$ by induction hypothesis, because the sum is alternating. I have tried more things, such as applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the expression:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{}
  2^0 \\
2^2 \\
\vdots \\
2^n
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{}
 |A_{11}|,
|A_{31}|,
\dots,
|A_{n+1,1}|
\end{array}
\right) > 2\left(
\begin{array}{}
  2^0 \\
2^2 \\
\vdots \\
2^{n-2}
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{}
 |A_{21}|,
|A_{41}|,
\dots,
|A_{n1}|
\end{array}
\right) $$

But I end up with a more difficult to prove inequality, because I can't find the proper relations between the cofactors of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multilinearity of the determinant. Let $A_n$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix which you defined. Subtract $2^{i-1}$ times the first row from the $i$-th row of $A_{n+1}$ for each $i \ge 2$. The result is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \ast \\ 0 & A_n \end{bmatrix}.$$ Thus $\det(A_{n+1}) = \det(A_n) = 1$ by induction.